# I'm having an issues with inline block and whitespace and CSS

Tags: css, whitespace

This was a repost because I horrendously screwed up the first post. I apologize for that.So I have two inline-block displayed DIVs and I want them to appear next to each other however I also want the text inside of the blocks to behave properly. As you can see by the demo the text in block2 is occurring outside of the text in block 1. I'm not pasting the CSS here as it is in the Fiddle.

```css
#container {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 35%;
  white-space: nowrap
}
#box1,
#box2 {
  border: 2px blue solid;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: normal
}
#box2 {
  white-space: normal
}
```

```html
<DIV id="container">
  <DIV id="box1">
    Box1
  </DIV>
  <DIV id="box2">
    Box2 More Box2 and More
  </DIV>
</DIV>
```

[JSFiddle Code](https://jsfiddle.net/c6y2dn4d/)

Thanks

Comment: Many users will not look at a question if there is not relevant code in the thing itself. Please, even if you have a fiddle up for demonstration purposes outside of Stack Overflow's snippet editor, include the relevant code in your post as it increases the likelihood of responses.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set width on both the child elements to constrain the text inside it, see the example below:

```css
#container {width:35%;white-space:nowrap; background: teal;}
#box1, #box2 {width: 30%; display:inline-block;white-space:normal; background: aqua;}
#box2 {width: 70%; white-space:normal; background: aqua;}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="box1">Box1</div>
    <div id="box2">Box2 More Box2 and More</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display:flex` on container.

Here is jsfiddle example https://jsfiddle.net/c6y2dn4d/1/

```css
#container {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 35%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: flex
}
#box1,
#box2 {
  border: 2px blue solid;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: normal
}
#box2 {
  white-space: normal;
  margin-left: 5px
}
```

```html
<DIV id="container">
  <DIV id="box1">
    Box1
  </DIV>
  <DIV id="box2">
    Box2 More Box2 and More
  </DIV>
</DIV>
```

Answer (score 0):

Would be this what you're looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/gwzn3ek3/

```
<DIV id="container">
    <DIV id="box1">
        Box1
    </DIV><DIV id="box2">
        Box2 More Box2 and More
    </DIV>
</DIV>
```

Basically, you can't have white spaces between the two inline-block markup, since it'll generate a small spacing between them.

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript for that go to your fiddle and add this javascript part to it

```
var box1 = document.getElementById("box1").offsetWidth;
var box2 = document.getElementById("box2").offsetWidth;
var newWidth = box2 + box1 +"px";
document.getElementById("container").style.width=newWidth;
```

This should work. Hope I could help you

Answer (score 0):

That seems like a `<table>` to me...

Try something like this:

```css
#container {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 35%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: table;
}
#box1,
#box2 {
  border: 2px blue solid;
  display: table-cell;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<DIV id="container">
  <DIV id="box1">
    Box1
  </DIV>
  <DIV id="box2">
    Box2 More Box2 and More
  </DIV>
</DIV>
```